# Cannot select language on website in Firefox on Linux, but can on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, language

My mother uses a Xubuntu computer for some basic surfing and mailing. When she visits the homepage of a local shopping store, she is greeted with a popup screen to select her preferred language. In Belgium, it's common to see a popup with a selection of either Dutch ('Nederlands') or French ('Frans'). However, clicking on either link doesn't do anything.

The website is that of Delhaize ([www.delhaize.be](http://www.delhaize.be)). I can bypass the popup once by adding /nl-be/ to the URL, but as soon as she clicks on a product or link, the popup reappears.

I've had a look at the settings for Firefox (version 108.0.1), they are basically the same as on my computers (privacy settings are set to standard, language is set to Dutch) and I can't seem to find any differences.

In Firefox I also tried to inspect the HTML code of the website, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out a reason why the buttons don't work on Xubuntu/Firefox, whereas they do work on my computer (Windows 10/Firefox).

Eventually I installed Chrome, but Chrome shows the exact same behaviour: both language buttons do not work.

Since Delhaize is a large company, I'm inclined to believe that the issue is on my side and not a "this website just doesn't work on Linux" issue.

Does anybody have any idea why these buttons don't work? And, more important, how can I get them to work so my mother can continue shopping?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the *choice* is stored in cookies, I'd look there for clues.

Comment: *Since Delhaize is a large company, I'm inclined to believe that the issue is on my side and not a "this website just doesn't work on Linux" issue.* I'll say that line of reasoning doesn't work, sadly. It's very likely really a bug on delhaize website's end, assuming you're not running any interesting addons

Comment: *Chrome shows the exact same behaviour* yeah, the website is broken; not your or your mama's fault. It doesn't work for me, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick check: if you force Firefox (using a plugin) to announce it's a firefox on windows instead of on linux, the website starts working. So, **it is the website that locks out Linux users**, based on the browser telling the server it's running on Linux.

So, short term: install the pluugin "User Agent Switcher" in your Firefox, and use its "Override for Domain" menu entry to switch to "Firefox/Windows" only on delhaize.be.

Medium term: Let the people running delhaize.be know that this is exactly what happens and that you're not willing to install a plugin just so that your mom can go shopping. Their website is broken, and it's in their commercial interest to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I've installed the plugin and the website now works, my mother will be very happy. I'll be sure to send an email to Delhaize to let them know, I agree that this is something they should solve, and frankly I'm amazed they haven't already...